# Develop Swipe and Delete function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I added the swipe and delete function but found that I cannot really delete and edit my note in the simulator. How to revise my code?

[image]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        print("index path of delete: \(indexPath)")
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    let rename = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        print("index path of edit: \(indexPath)")
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    let swipeActionConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [rename, delete])
    swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return swipeActionConfig
}
```

Comment: Please include code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything in either your `rename` or `delete` closures besides printing. Without knowing anything about the structure of the app, it'd be impossible to suggest how to actually implement in the features.

Comment: Please remove an element in the data set you have, and call `tableView.deleteRows(at: )` to be applied.